# Jquery - add class on hover

Tags: jquery

I want when mouse goes on `li` jquery add a class to the element:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myMenu = $('.menu').children('li');

myMenu.on({
  mouseenter: function() { $( this ).addClass( "is_hovered" ); },
  mouseleave: function() { $( this ).removeClass( "is_hovered" ); }
});
</script>
```

But I want to remove class only if mouse goes on another `li`, if not **keep** class on element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the mouseleave handler in that case, on mouseenter remove the hovered class from other elements

```
var myMenu = $('.menu li');

myMenu.mouseenter(function () {
    myMenu.filter('.is_hovered').removeClass("is_hovered");
    $(this).addClass("is_hovered");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HCWw7/)

Answer (score 1):

This will work, when you mouse over li it will add `is_hovered` to li and remove from other li.

```
$(".menu li").mouseover(function(){
    $(".menu li").removeClass("is_hovered");
    $(this).addClass("is_hovered");
});
```